# Combination with selective boundaries

Tags: statistics, combinations

Im in a statistics course and I am honestly quite stuck on this problem. I really would love some guidance!

"A shelf contains 9 different fiction books and 6 different nonfiction books. A woman selects 4 books at random from the shelf. How many different selections are possible if at least 3 books must be nonfiction?"

I understand that I need to do:
15C4 - (the combinations where less than three books are fiction) but I am having some problems getting the right answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

so I actually ended up figuring this one out (funny that I did right after posting it).

Incase someone else needs it,

1) 6C3 * 9

2) (the previous answer) + 6C4

This is because I first needed to take the number of combinations considering just selecting three nonfiction books. I then needed to multiply those combinations by nine due to the multiplication rule of addition. This give the number of combinations for any set of three non-fiction books and 1 fiction book. So, finally I needed to add the combinations of all four selections being non-fiction.